# maximum value of xor operation

Tags: algorithm

I came up with this question.

> There is an encryption algorithm which uses bitwise XOR operations extensively. This encryption algorithm uses a sequence of non-negative integers x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>n</sub> as key. To implement this algorithm efficiently, Xorq needs to find maximum value for (a xor x<sub>j</sub>) for given integers a, p and q such that p <= j <= q. Help Xorq to implement this function.
>
> #### Input
>
> First line of input contains a single integer T (1<=T<=6). T test cases follow.
>
> First line of each test case contains two integers N and Q separated by a single space (1 <= N <= 100,000; 1 <= Q <= 50,000). Next line contains N integers x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>n</sub> separated by a single space (0 <= x<sub>j</sub> < 215). Each of next Q lines describe a query which consists of three integers a<sub>i</sub>, p<sub>i</sub> and q<sub>i</sub> (0 <= a<sub>i</sub> < 215, 1<= p<sub>i</sub> <= q<sub>i</sub> <= N).
>
> #### Output
>
> For each query, print the maximum value for (a<sub>i</sub> xor x<sub>j</sub>) such that p<sub>i</sub> <= j <= q<sub>i</sub> in a single line.
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 1
> 15 8
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
> 10 6 10
> 1023 7 7
> 33 5 8
> 182 5 10
> 181 1 13
> 5 10 15
> 99 8 9
> 33 10 14
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 13
> 1016
> 41
> 191
> 191
> 15
> 107
> 47
> ```
>
> #### Explanation
>
> ```
> First Query (10 6 10): x6 xor 10 = 12,
>     x7 xor 10 = 13, x8 xor 10 = 2, x9 xor 10 = 3, x10 xor 10 = 0,
>     therefore answer for this query is 13.
> Second Query (1023 7 7): x7 xor 1023 = 1016,
>     therefore answer for this query is 1016.
> Third Query (33 5 8): x5 xor 33 = 36, x6 xor 33 = 39,
>     x7 xor 33 = 38, x8 xor 33 = 41, therefore answer for this query is 41.
> Fourth Query (182 5 10): x5 xor 182 = 179,
>     x6 xor 182 = 176, x7 xor 182 = 177, x8 xor 182 = 190,
>     x9 xor 182 = 191, x10 xor 182 = 188,
>     therefore answer for this query is 191.
> ```

I tried this by first making the numbers length(in binary)
in the given range equal and then comparing 'a' bit by
bit with the particular xj values.But it is time exceeding.
Maximum time limit in java is 5sec.

Comment: *"Xorq needs to find maximum value for (a xor xj)  
for given integers a,p and q such that p<=j<=q."* What's Xorq? What's xj?

Comment: If you want to make things as slow as possible, by all means do math with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't gone through your code in detail, but you seem to have loops over the range of r = p - 1; r < q - 1; r++, and it would be nice not to have to do this.

Given ai, we want to find a value of xi in the given range with as many of its top bits the inverse of ai as possible. Everything is between 0 and 2^15, so there aren't many bits to worry about. For n = 1 to 15 you could divide the xi up according to its n highest bits, so dividing it into 2, 4, 8, 16.. 32768 portions. For each portion keep a list in sorted order of the positions where each possible value is found, so for the top bit you will have two lists, one giving the positions at which the bit pattern is 0.............. and one giving the position at which the bit pattern is 1............ For each triple, you can use binary chop on a particular portion to find if there are any positions within your range at which the top n bits have the bit pattern you are looking for. If they do, fine. If not you will have to accept that one of the xor positions is 0 and slightly modify the pattern you look for with one more top bit set.

The setup cost is 15 linear passes over the xi, which is probably less time than it takes you to read it in. For each line you could do 15 binary chops to see which values of xi match in the top n bits, and modify the pattern of top bits you look for if you can't match a particular bit.

I think your program would be clearer if you separated the I/O from the problem code by making the problem code a separate subroutine. This would also make it easier to compare one version of the problem code with another, to see which is faster and if they both get the same answer.

Comment: what is the portion 2,4,6,8... and triplet i can't understand clearly can you please elaborate

Comment: Oops - I meant 2, 4, 8, 16, ... If you select on the top bit you have just two sublists, on the top 2 bits, 4 sublists, on the top 3 bits 8 sublists, and so on. Sorry about that - I've edited it.

Comment: i think it is taking more time by dividing into portions.i think in the given subrange i compare all of them with 'a' bit by bit from msb to lsb untill amswer is found.here suppose all values inthe given range has same value in the bit position(i.e either 1 or 0)then skip that bit and move to next bit.this repeats untill one value remains.

Comment: It may depend on the parameters provided, but since the cost of my approach does not depend on q - p there will be at least some parameters, with large values of q - p, where it is faster.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest inefficiency that I can spot in the original algorithm is that `N` can be up to 100,000 but `a` and `x` can only go up to 214. So I would write pseudocode something like this:

```
bool set[256] = { false };
for (j = p; j <= q; j++) set[x[j]] = true;
for (k = 255; !set[a ^ j]; k--);
return k;
```

This reduces the number of `xor` operations to 256 in the worst case.

Comment: there is a typo in there, the problem says 1<x<=2^15...which complicates things...a lot