# data structure for special type of queries

Tags: c#, java, c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have faced some problems of this kind. Suppose we are given an array `A` of `n` elements where `n` is around `1` million. We are given queries of form `'p q'`. In each query, we have to perform some operation on the elements `A[p]` to `A[q]`.

- This operation is some ordinary operation like `XOR` or something. For ex- taking XOR of every number in A( from index p to q )with a given number m. For ex- `A[p]^m,A[p+1]^m..A[q]^m`

If we are given thousands of queries of type 'p q' then, we do repetitive calculations for overlapping ranges (for ex.-`p1<p2<q1<q2`). If have a space/time tradeoff, I would prefer to do my work faster even if it takes more space. So, I am concentrating on time not much on space.

My question is - **Is there any data structure which can process these type of queries(having some range which repeats in further queries) efficiently.** What I can think of is something like- doing some pre-processing and saving things in a data structure. And then updating and processing as we receive further queries.

Can someone suggest some data structure which is helpful in processing the queries which are concerned with some ranges (specially when the ranges are further repeated extensively)?

- This is the original question for which I need the data structure-
  [maximum value of xor operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395549/maximum-value-of-xor-operation)

Comment: There for sure are, but one thing to consider is a space/time tradeoff. When you're talking millions of ints it's a good and this isn't for some embedded system, you can probably heavily cache

Comment: Do you need to have the result of every `A[p] xor A[p+1], A[p] xor A[p+2]`...`A[q-1] xor A[q]` or an aggregate like `A[p] xor A[p+1] xor A[p+2] ... A[q]`? For the latter there is a rather simple structure that will do it.

Comment: @SergeyL. I have updated. please check.

Comment: @Avram I have updated. please check.

Comment: If you could give more details on the exact operations and how much overlap there is, someone might know a niche data structure which fits it. Right now, I doubt you can beat a simple array (possibly multiple arrays to cache results of these operations), as extremely cache friendly and compact, and extremely fast to iterate over, and is amendable to SIMD vectorization...

Comment: What do PHP, C++, and Java have to do with the question?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I know about interval trees. But I could find a way to implement this problem with them in an efficient way. If you have any direction in mind, please suggest.

Comment: Also, this sounds like something that the indices a RDBMS uses would be good for. Try a B+ tree with chained leaf nodes. That's two `log(n)` lookups per query, with the results cacheable until the underlying data structure is modified.

Comment: @millimoose Sorry for wrong tagging but that was just to increase views of the question.

Comment: @user1708762 Is spamming tag subpages something you think is the right thing to do?

Comment: @delnan For your clarity, please consider the operation is only XOR which is used as mentioned in the question. Overlaps are huge. for ex- p1=5,q1=99999. p2=12, q2=99989. you can see how repetitive calculation is being done in processing second query. Btw please clarify what you said about cache. I couldn't get it!

Comment: @millimoose No, That's not. But I was not getting any views for this question so I edited the tags. I apologize again!

Comment: @delnan Please check the reference question that I have added.

Comment: @millimoose Please check the reference question that I have added.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Please check the reference question that I have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I thought of was a [Segment Tree with lazy propagation](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Segment_tree#Lazy_propagation) but it only really applies if the query you described is really an update to the table and doesn't return the result. So, there would be an update[p q] operation and a query[p q]. The first just updates using an operation like you described and the second returns the values from the range.

Also see [this](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Segment_Trees).

Answer (score 0):

For each k in the range 0 to log(n) store an array A[k] of length n/2**k.

The contents of A[k][i] will represent the elements in the array from index i*2**k to (i+1)*2**k-1.

When you want to operate on a range you break the range into the biggest chunks possible and update the corresponding entries in A[k].

e.g. if you had a range from 16->33 you would update just A[4][1] (representing 16->31) and A[1][16] (representing 32->33)

When you want to access the combined value in an element you need to combine the operations in each of the log(n) arrays.

e.g. to access 5 you would need to combine operations in A[0][5] and A[1][2] and A[2][1] and A[3][0] etc.

This should give O(log(n)) cost for each operation on a range, and for each access of an element.