# Optimizing a Standard Iterative Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption, optimization, c-preprocessor

In reference to the problem challenge here:
[Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/xor-key)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    int T,*x,i,j,k,a,res,pres;
    long Q,N,p,q;
    cin>>T;
    for(k=0;k<T;k++)
    {
        cin>>N>>Q;
        x=new int[N];
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            cin>>x[i];
        }
        for(i=0;i<Q;i++)
        {
            pres=-999;
            cin>>a>>p>>q;
            for(j=p-1;j<q;j++)
            {
                res=a xor x[j];
                if(pres<res)
                {
                    pres=res;
                }
            }
            cout<<pres<<endl;

        }
        delete [] x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting Time Limit Exceeded(implying the problem can be optimized) on the larger problems(N=100000)(N,Q,T maxing out). I figure I need to optimize the algorithm using some kind of preprocessing. My Solution is of O(NQT) for the whole problem. The problem will need to evaluate for all the possible XORs for the given limits in a query. So, The problem would need to go (q-p)[Can be at max N] times for a query. I cannot figure a way to avoid this. A Hit or a direction would be really appreciated. I am thinking of implementing a heap somehow, so that it deducts the query a from the heap and den a max heap is made to see the max difference and den xors. But that too would take O(NQT)

Comment: Why do your loops start at 1?  Why do you allocate without deallocating?  Why do you declare variables far from the point of use?  Why do you `using namespace std;`?  Clean up the code first, and get huge constant factors.

Comment: Cleaned up the Itsy Bitsy Things. My main code is all cleaned up. This was kinda raw before i cleaned the unecessary stuff. Started from 1 because initially wasnt getting the result,  just to make sure everythings 1 to N, so dat goes according to the algo i thought.

Comment: Probably better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Yakk, I think your a little harsh with `using namespace std;`, this isn't in a header, so its common and perfectly acceptable for most code

Comment: @AbhishekBansal - Its the algorithm which i need to figure out. the code is fine and works out for the problem. I need to optimize this to take lesser time.

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri The general guideline is that if the code does not work, then it is meant for Stack Overflow, however if the code works but needs optimization / review, then codereview is a better place. Still I consider this a very good question and I mentioned the comment only for your benefit since it maybe more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Same question has been asked here I believe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395549/maximum-value-of-xor-operation

Comment: For starters, replace all usage of std::cin, std::cout with scanf/printf or getc/putc

Comment: Move the new/delete  outside the loop. Rellocate only if the new required size exceeds the already allocated one. Use std::vector for the buffer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think fiddling with what you wrote will get you much in the way of speed. You want something with a better time complexity.

From the question, I assume they want something that is O(log N) per query. My initial thought was a [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree), but I couldn't find a way to use them to maximize `a ^ x[i]`.

I believe you're supposed to use the fact that all numbers are less than `2^15`. Another thing to note is that you want to maximize a `xor` operation. Let's say you have (in binary)

```
a = b_1 b_2 ... b_n
```

You either have that all `x[j]` with `p <= j <= q` have the most significant bit equal to the `b_1`, or there are some `x[j]` for which the most significant bit is the complement of `b_1`. This is because `b xor ~b = 1` for `b in {0,1}`. You select only those `j` for which the MSB is the complement of `b_1`, and continue with next bit (that corresponding to `b_2`).

The problem is that a brute-force implementation of this is worse than what you're already doing, but it might help you towards a faster implementation.

Comment: Well doing the XOR operation only with the numbers having MSB of x[j] being complement of a will reduce the no. of XOR operations. but wouldnt it also add N number of comparisions to decide which of them have the complemented MSB? Wont that make the time complexity same as it was?

Comment: Yes, that's the point where my method breaks down. I don't know how to solve your problem fully, but I believe it has something to do with the numbers all being relatively small (less than 2^15).

I'll edit my answer if I think of something better.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

- All the calls to `cin` make it impossible to measure this code's performance. you should read all the data in advance from files.
- Don't allocate `x` every look, allocate once with `malloc` and call `realloc` to make the buffer longer if needed. Memory allocations can slow things down.

The inner loop is very simple so the compiler can vectorize it. Make sure this actually happens by looking at the disassembly. If not, use SSE intrinsics to work on 4 or 8 8 elements at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the modified code with the suggestions I made in the comments.

Avoid C++ iostreams in performance sensitive code. (FWIW, avoid iostreams in general)
Avoid allocation/deallocation as much as possible. In the code below, `vector::resize` will
take care for the vector to always have at least the required space.
Not performance, but readability wise: use spaces aronud operators. Declare variables close
to the wherethey ared used.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int T;
    std::vector<int> x;

    std::scanf ("%d", &T);
    for (int k = 0; k < T ; ++k) {

        int N, Q;
        std::scanf ("%d%d", &N, &Q);
        x.resize (N);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            std::scanf ("%d", &x[i]);

        for (int i = 0; i < Q; ++i) {
            int a, p, q;
            std::scanf ("%d%d%d", &a, &p, &q);

            int pres = -999;
            for(int j = p - 1; j < q; ++j)
                pres = std::max (pres, a ^ x[j]);

            std::printf ("%d\n", pres);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```